# How to know event added successfully in android calendar

Tags: android, events, button, android-intent, calendar

how can I know event added successfully in an android calendar,
I want to change my button which calls an edit intent to the calendar.
I am able to add the event but how can I check that user added the event or cancel that calendar event prompt.
kindly give help.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                    intent.putExtra("title","Fajr Prayer");
                    intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION,parser.city+" , "+parser.country);
                    Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR,hour);
                    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
                    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR,hour);
                    endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute+30);
                    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
                    startTime.getTimeInMillis());
                    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
                    endTime.getTimeInMillis());
                    startActivity(intent);
```

I tried this code to add the event but know i am unable to find out how to get indication of successful calendar event addition.